# PyQt crashing when trying to round variable in label

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a widget that prints into a label how far the mouse is from the center. Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MouseTracker(QWidget):
    distance_from_center = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mouse Tracker')
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        distance_from_center = ((event.y() - 250) + (event.x() - 500))**0.5
        self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "Distance from center: " + str(round(distance_from_center)))       

    def drawPoints(self, qp, x, y):
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPoint(x, y)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MouseTracker()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is where the problem lies:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    distance_from_center = ((event.y() - 250) + (event.x() - 500))**0.5
    self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) + "Distance from center: " + str(round(distance_from_center)))
```

If I remove the `round` function around `distance_from_center`, it prints a value but it's not pretty. How can I make this work? Why can't I simply round?

Comment: change ((event.y() - 250) + (event.x() - 500))**0.5 to ((event.y() - 250)**2 + (event.x() - 500)**2)**0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the Euclidean distance you must change:

```
((event.y() - 250) + (event.x() - 500))**0.5
```

to

```
((event.y() - 250)**2 + (event.x() - 500)**2)**0.5
```

Comment: Thank you! Good eye